# Timber and ACF how to get sub field object of ACF field group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

**Using Timber for Wordpress, I'm trying to loop through an ACF field group and get for each sub_field the value and the label.**

My ACF field group is named *apartment_specs*

I can get the **values** of each sub_field with:

```
{% for item in post.get_field('apartment_specs') %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I can get the **labels** of each sub_field with:

```
{% for item in post.field_object('apartment_specs').sub_fields %}
  <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't really get the two things in the same loop.

Is there in Timber anything like the ACF' get_sub_field_object? How'd it work?

Comment: what else is in item? what do you get when you {{ dump(item) }} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `get_sub_field_object` function.

Something like this might help you:

```
{% for key,item in fields.contracts %}
    {% set object = function('get_sub_field_object', key) %}
    {{ dump(object) }}
    <li>{{ object.label }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is a very simple example. For easier usage you can create Timber function or filter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @maxim!
I was able to get what I needed by simply using:

```
{% for key, item in post.get_field('apartment_specs') %}
  <li class="{{key}}">{{item}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying your solution in another more complex situation